# Parsing kafka protobuf event through string deserialization

Tags: java, apache-kafka, protocol-buffers

I am receiving protobuf messages on kafka, the consumer is configured to deserialize the events using

```
value.deserializer = org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer
```

If I use `parseFrom(byte[] data)` method of `com.google.protobuf.Parser` by passing byte array of the deserialized event string, the method throws following exception:

```
com.google.protobuf.InvalidProtocolBufferException: While parsing a protocol message, the input ended unexpectedly in the middle of a field.  This could mean either than the input has been truncated or that an embedded message misreported its own length.
```

If I instead deserialize kafka events with

```
value.deserializer = org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.ByteArrayDeserializer
```

and directly pass the byte array thus received to `parseFrom`, protobuf is correctly parsed without any exception.

Why does the second way work, but the first does not?

Answer (score 2):

You are using a **String deserializer**, which expects certain special characters to define the message's limits. It tries to deserialize a STRING but he receives just a bunch of bytes with a format the consumer doesn't expect at all.

You have a producer which serializes with `ByteArraySerializer`, so your consumer must deserialize it with a `ByteArrayDeserializer`.

Try producing with a `org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer` if you really want to automatically deserialize in String format.